# momentjs deprecated warning not going away

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-moment

```
somestringvar = moment(entry.expirationDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MMM-DD-YYYY").toString();
```

The date is correctly converted to the format I need like Nov-11-2018 but I just cannot get rid of that infamous moment js deprecated warning. Tried many combinations. The warning I get is 
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers

Please advise how to get rid of this warning. I am using latest angular version and typescript code. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to stick my neck out and say that I don't believe this is the line of code that is generating the warning.  As I understand it, you can only get the deprecation warning when passing a single string into `moment(...)` but the line of code you show above passes two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get around is changing the moment constructor to `moment(new Date(entry.expirationDate))`.

Comment: The line that was throwing the warning was actually like  moment('12/25/2018') and not the one I thought it was which I mentioned in my question. That fixed it. Thanks